# How to build es6 in angular2 by babel to structure that I can debug?

Tags: angularjs, gulp, babeljs

I'm learning `angular2 + es6`.
And I have a problem when use `gulp` to build.
I clone one simple app from https://github.com/shuhei/babel-angular2-app, and when build, it use `babelify` map all file to one file `bundle.js`, it work well, but I can not debug.

*structure*

[image]

*gulpfile*

```
import gulp from 'gulp';
import gutil, { PluginError } from 'gulp-util';
import source from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import buffer from 'vinyl-buffer';

import browserify from 'browserify';
import watchify from 'watchify';
import babelify from 'babelify';

import del from 'del';

gulp.task('copy', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/index.html')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});

gulp.task('build', ['copy'], () => {
  const b = browserify('src/index.js')
    .transform(babelify);
  return bundle(b);
});

gulp.task('default', ['copy', 'watch']);

function bundle(b) {
  return b.bundle()
    .on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(e.stack);
    })
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(buffer())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
}
```

How to build one structure that I can debug.

*ex: structure*

[image]

Please help me.
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use source maps. I just happened to make a [yeoman generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-webpack-quick) for this exact purpose of learning and experimentation.

Set up your project using it, after which follow these steps :

1. Install angular (`npm install --save angular`)
2. Write your code in ES6 inside the `src` directory
3. Debug your code in google chromes developer console

Since the code includes sourcemaps, any error in your code will map to the original ES6 file and not the compiled bundle.js file. Additionally, you can now put breakpoints in your ES6 code on chrome, and it will work as expected.